# Replace special characters with words in python

Tags: python, regex

For the following string:

`s = The \r\n sun shines, that's fine [latex]not\r\nt for \r\n everyone[/latex] and if it rains, \r\nit Will Be better.`.

If I want to replace `\n\r` by `' '` between `[latex]` and `[/latex]`, I can use:

```
re.sub("\[latex\][^]]*\[/latex\]", lambda x:x.group(0).replace('\r\n',' '), s)
```

which works fine.

However, if the input is:

```
s = some\r\nthing\r\n[latex]\\[\x08egin{array}{*{20}{l}}\r\n{{\rm{dA}} = {\rm{wdy}}:}\\\r\n{{\rm{dF}} = {\rm{P}}\\;{\rm{dA}} = \rho {\rm{g}}\\left( {{\rm{H}}-{\rm{y}}} \right)\\;\\omega \\;{\rm{dy}}}\r\n\\end{array}\\][/latex]\r\n
```

and I use the same expression, nothing gets replaced.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: It's because your regex matches nothing in the second case.

Comment: Use [`r"(?s)\[latex].*?\[/latex]"`](https://ideone.com/heODCc). Also note that your strings also contain single `\r` - you might also want to replace that.

Comment: Does you input string contain the linebreaks or literal `\r\n`s?

Comment: it contains literals \r\n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to presence of `]` before `[/latex]` in second input. Also better to use raw strings for your input and regex.

You can use this regex for search:

```
\[latex\].*?\[/latex\]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DXv0ep/2)

**Code:**

```
>>> s = r"some\r\nthing\r\n[latex]\\[\x08egin{array}{*{20}{l}}\r\n{{\rm{dA}} = {\rm{wdy}}:}\\\r\n{{\rm{dF}} = {\rm{P}}\\;{\rm{dA}} = \rho {\rm{g}}\\left( {{\rm{H}}-{\rm{y}}} \right)\\;\\omega \\;{\rm{dy}}}\r\n\\end{array}\\][/latex]\r\n"
>>> print re.sub(r"\[latex\].*?\[/latex\]", lambda x:x.group(0).replace(r'\r\n', ' '), s)
some\r\nthing\r\n[latex]\\[\x08egin{array}{*{20}{l}} {{\rm{dA}} = {\rm{wdy}}:}\\ {{\rm{dF}} = {\rm{P}}\\;{\rm{dA}} = \rho {\rm{g}}\\left( {{\rm{H}}-{\rm{y}}} \right)\\;\\omega \\;{\rm{dy}}} \\end{array}\\][/latex]\r\n
```

[Code Demo](http://ideone.com/yYmiKn)

Comment: Check code and generated output in answer. It is replacing `\r\n` by `" "` in output.

Comment: Also as Wiktor commented if your input spans newlines then use `(?s)` in your regex.

Comment: *Also better to use raw strings for your input and regex.* is half incorrect. If the input contains *linebreaks*, no raw string literal is necessary. Only if the input has ``\`` char followed with `r` then ``\`` and ``n``, then yes, use the raw string literal for the input.